# Error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Uic'ing ......"

Tags: c++, moc

I am trying to run a Project but i couldn't. I am getting Error PRJ0019. Could you please help me how i can get rid of this error.

Here is my buildLog ;

> @echo off
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe select_model.ui -o .\select_model.h
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe select_model.ui -i select_model.h -o
>   .\select_model.cpp
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\moc.exe .\select_model.h -o .\moc_select_model.cpp
>
> if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
>
> goto VCEnd
>
> :VCReportError
>
> echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from
>   "Uic'ing select_model.ui..."
>
> exit 1
>
> :VCEnd ] Creating command line
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000190767304.bat"
>   Creating temporary file
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000290767304.bat"
>   with contents [ @echo off
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe previewform.ui -o .\previewform.h
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe previewform.ui -i previewform.h -o
>   .\previewform.cpp
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\moc.exe .\previewform.h -o .\moc_previewform.cpp
>
> if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
>
> goto VCEnd
>
> :VCReportError
>
> echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from
>   "Uic'ing previewform.ui..."
>
> exit 1
>
> :VCEnd ] Creating command line
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000290767304.bat"
>   Creating temporary file
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000390767304.bat"
>   with contents [ @echo off
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe messageform.ui -o .\messageform.h
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe messageform.ui -i messageform.h -o
>   .\messageform.cpp
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\moc.exe .\messageform.h -o .\moc_messageform.cpp
>
> if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
>
> goto VCEnd
>
> :VCReportError
>
> echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from
>   "Uic'ing messageform.ui..."
>
> exit 1
>
> :VCEnd ] Creating command line
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000390767304.bat"
>   Creating temporary file
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000490767304.bat"
>   with contents [ @echo off
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe mainform.ui -o .\mainform.h
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\uic.exe mainform.ui -i mainform.h -o .\mainform.cpp
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\moc.exe .\mainform.h -o .\moc_mainform.cpp
>
> if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
>
> goto VCEnd
>
> :VCReportError
>
> echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from
>   "Uic'ing mainform.ui..."
>
> exit 1
>
> :VCEnd ] Creating command line
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000490767304.bat"
>   Creating temporary file
>   "c:\Users\musa\Documents\Hobby\LSSDK_NO_WSQ\EXAMPLE\lsclient_test\Debug\BAT00000590767304.bat"
>   with contents [ @echo off
>
> d:\qt_4.8.2\bin\moc.exe imgview.h -o moc_imgview.cpp
>
> if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
>
> goto VCEnd
>
> :VCReportError
>
> echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from
>   "Moc'ing imgview.h..."
>
> exit 1
>
> :VCEnd